# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, type-inference

Does anybody know how I can solve this error that I'm getting? The error is received on the first line in the following chunk of code:

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Message")
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding the return type in the closure like this code:

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Message")
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}()
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message is a bit misleading, the problem is that you did
not specify the generic placeholder type for the variable.

You can either add an explicit return type to the closure, as @Mukesh
suggested, in that case the type annotation on the variable is not
needed:

```
let fetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
    // ...
    return frc
}()
```

Or fully specify the type of the variable, then the closure return
type is inferred automatically:

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
    // ...
    return frc
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two** issues:

1. As mentioned in the other answers you have to specify the generic type, in your case the ideal type is the concrete `NSManagedObject` subclass.
2. **The declaration of an `NSFetchedResultsController` requires at least one sort descriptor**.

   ```
   let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Message> = {
       let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
       fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "somekey", ascending: true]
       let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
       let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
       let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
       return frc
   }()
   ```